# Forbidding more than 1 instance of a Model saved to DB (Django)?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model and I would like to limit the amount of instances it has in the DB to 1. However, I would like to allow that 1 instance to be edited and updated.

I tried using a `@receiver` signal to count the number of instances before allowing to save, but if I limit it that way, it would not let the admin edit the instance either.

Is there a way to differentiate between a create vs. an edit action in the signal sender?

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=myModel)
def checkLimit(sender, **kwargs):
    count = sender.objects.count()
    if count > 1:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

Comment: I don't have access to `myModel.objects` from with the `myModel class`. the `@receiver` gives me access with the `sender` prop.